# Slow getimagesize from local server

Tags: php, curl, getimagesize

I am trying to fetch image from few external sites as I’m trying to develop link sharing website for my project. I downloaded file with curl to local server but getimagesize is still very slow (30 seconds). I’m a newbie to php any help would be appreciated. 
Here is the code:

```
function check_url($value)
{
$value = trim($value);
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
$value = strtr($value, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)));
$value = strip_tags($value);
$value = htmlspecialchars($value);
return $value;
}   

$curl = curl_init();

$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'link');
$fp = fopen($temp_file, "w");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close($curl);

///
$html = file_get_contents($temp_file);
fclose ($fp);
unlink($temp_file);

if($html) {
//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

 //get and display what you need:
 $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
 $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

 for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
 {
 $meta = $metas->item($i);
 if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
 $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
 }

 // fetch images
 $image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
 preg_match_all($image_regex, $html, $img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
 $images_array = $img[1];

 ?>
 <div class="images">
<?php
 $k=1;
 for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($images_array);$i++)
{
if(@$images_array[$i])
{
    if(@getimagesize(@$images_array[$i]))
    {
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) =   getimagesize(@$images_array[$i]);
        if($width >= 80 && $height >= 80 ){

        echo "<img src='".@$images_array[$i]."' width='100' id='".$k."' >";

        $k++;
        }
    }
}
}

?>




<input type="hidden" name="total_images" id="total_images" value="<?php echo --$k?>" />
</div>
<div class="info">

    <label class="title">
        <?php  echo @$title; ?>
    </label>
    <br clear="all" />
    <label class="url">
        <?php  echo substr($url ,0,35); ?>
    </label>
    <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
    <label class="desc">
        <?php  echo @$description; ?>
    </label>
    <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />

    <label style="float:left"><img src="prev.png" id="prev" alt="" /><img src="next.png" id="next" alt="" /></label>

    <label class="totalimg">
        Total <?php echo $k?> images
    </label>
    <br clear="all" />

</div>
<?php
} else {
echo "Please enter a valid url";
}
?>
```

Comment: You could start by removing all that error suppression.

Comment: @tereško removing the error suppression's didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not surprising.  You are looping through all of those images.  Downloading those images and then getting their sizes can take significant time.

At best, you can load those images asynchronously and cache results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but curl downloads the content fast enough the problem is with getting the images size. And why would looping it through take that long?

Comment: Put some profiling code around your loop to see how long each `getimagesize()` call takes.